# How to use an ArrayList as Query parameter in retrofit

Tags: retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
@GET("values")
Call<List<Values>> getResult(@Query("ids") List<String> ids);
```

My desired request is something like this:

```
server.com/values?ids=abc%2Cdef%2Cghi%2Cjkl
```

Actual request is this:

```
server.com/values?ids=abc&ids=def&ids=ghi&ids=jkl
```

How can I achieve the desired request?

Comment: I think you can pass as pre-formatted string or override toString() method according to [this](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/611)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, figured this out. This was my approach to going this:

First, convert ArrayList into an encoded string:

```
String uriString = null;
try {
       uriString = URLEncoder.encode(TextUtils.join(",", ids), "utf-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
       // Catch the exception
}
```

And then do the following while making the retrofit call:

```
@GET("values")
Call<List<Values>> getResult(@Query(encode=true, value="ids") String ids);
```

Setting encode = true is extremely important, otherwise your % will be further encoded and you will never be able make the desired call.